# how to call a cout function to ofstream output file

Tags: c++, printing, output, fstream, ofstream

I have a function void displayList() that displays a list of a set.
in the main function I also have

```
ofstream outputFile(output.txt)
```

how do I call displayList and prints it in output.txt? Thanks.

displaylist is just some bunch of cout lines

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume your DisplayList is currently something like:

```
void DisplayList() { 
   cout << "a" << a << "\n";
}
```

I would rewrite it to become two overloaded functions:

```
void DisplayList(std::ostream &os) { 
    os << "a" << a << "\n";
}

void DisplayList() { DisplayList(std::cout); }
```

Then your existing code can continue to call `DisplayList()` with no parameters and get the current behavior. Code that wants to specify the destination file instead, can call:

```
Displaylist(outputFile);
```

And the output will got to the file they specified instead of `cout`.

This could be done as a function with a default argument instead, but under the circumstances, I think a pair of overloaded functions is probably simpler.

Comment: I tried doing so but what does it mean when it says ostream has not been declared? thank you.

Comment: @LeonardLie: You probably haven't included the correct header in that file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's:

```
outputFile << displayList();
```